# How to Expose SQL Server Hosted on Intranet to Connect Remotely

Tags: sql-server, iis, url-rewriting, tedious

I am trying to remote connect to a SQL Server that is hosted on a company intranet.  Ultimately, I would like to connect in with something like tedious and get the data into a web application via a REST API.

I followed this tutorial: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/

1. Entered the `client_net_address:1433` for the inbound rule.
2. Disabled SSL Offloading
3. Entered the public facing IP of the server in the outbound `To:` field but changed the last digits. e.g. xxx.xxx.xxx.100

When I try logging in with tedious I get a connection timeout error using the following config:

```
let config = {
  userName: "**",
  password: "**",
  server: "xxx.xxx.xxx.100",
  options:{
    port: 1433,
    database: "db_name",
    encrypt: true
  }
}
```

What steps must I take to connect remotely to a SQL database hosted on an intranet?

Currently I VPN in and can query from SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

Comment: Do you mean local network? or internet? well the only difference  between those is: You need some configuration on your router and the firewall to access your server via internet.

Comment: The database is on a local network.

Comment: Do you know of any tutorials I could follow to get the db setup for remote access?  The server is running IIS Manager and SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is working for node module mssql version 3.3.0 and SQL Server 2008.

Use `npm install mssql@3.3.0` and connectivity should work properly.

Version 4 of the mssql module has breaking changes.